# EOF representation in Windows

Tags: operating-system, interrupt

Would it be correct to represent `EOF` as `CTRL-C` on Windows? If not, what is a proper representation?

I am asking because it seems, that `OS` is interpreting it as an interrupt before program has a chance to interpret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> on Windows.